# plotting a chart with dates on the x-axis in mmm-yy format

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a chart in MATLAB. I have read that datetick is the way to go however I cannot get it to work. The error message is below the example of my code. te_result_struct.comp_dates is a vector containing the dates in a number format. If I plot the chat without trying to format the dates everything works.

```
figure(1)
plot(te_result_struct.comp_dates, te_result_struct.te_diff)
datetick(te_result_struct.comp_dates, 12)
```

SWITCH expression must be a scalar or string constant.

Error in datetick>parseinputs (line 352)
    switch v{1}

Error in datetick (line 109)
[axh,nin,ax,dateform,keep_ticks,keep_limits] = parseinputs(varargin);

Error in tracking_error_comp_ret (line 74)
    datetick(te_result_struct.comp_dates, 12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `datetick` is the *axis* to which you are applying, not the values of the labels.  Try

```
datetick(gca,12);
```

This uses the built-in pre-defined "format 12" which is `'mmmyy'` - see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html